# typeahead with get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm having problems with the bootstrap typeahead, here's my code:

```
 $('#search').typeahead({
     source: function (typeahead, query) {
         $.get('search.php?value=' + query, function (data) {
             return typeahead.process(data);
         });
     }
 });
```

It fires the get request and I get the wanted result back when I look in my network-window in Chrome. But the callback function from the get request only fires when my search-field is empty, very strange.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) AJAX source should be used this way:

```
$('#search').typeahead({
    source: function (query, process) {
        $.get('search.php?value=' + query, process);
    }
});
```

Comment: Lol fml.. I echoed something from my search.php that turned out to be a parsed error for json. It works now with the orginal code. Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: I am using the Twitter TypeAhead and they changed everything. Those code will bug since it requires remote/local/prefetch as a mandatory attribute.